# Multiple Pull Requests from single Pull Request

Tags: git, github

There is a scenario where a pull request was created from changes over longer duration and hence included changes to multiple parts of project. The code reviewers team wants this pull request to be abandoned and multiple smaller pull requests to be created.

After initial research, it looks infeasible to pick changes of a particular folder/directory from a pull request and create a smaller pull request.

Some commits have changes across folders so cherry picking is not feasible

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What about `cherry-pick` the related commits of a small feature and create a Pull request?

Comment: I cannot cherry pick the commits as there are 100+ commits and each commit has changes across folders. The ask is to create PR for changes in a particular code directory

Comment: i would branch from each commit that need to be PR (read as each point in the history that must be PR), i would be in my point of view more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

get the all commit to a particular folder

```
git log -- path/to/folder
```

then squash the commit ([squashing commits](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html))

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Lets say the 10 commits spanned changes across 3 folders, How do i create 3 PRs out of those changes ?

Comment: roll back the last 10 commit. 1) take one folder and get all the commit(using cherry pick) in that folder from a previously created local repo  and squash it to one commit follow the same for the other folder and finally you will get 3 commit.()

Answer (score 0):

- make sure you don't have any uncommitted work
- checkout the PR to temporary branch

  git checkout -b pr_splitting_branch top_of_the_PR
- now, keeping the changes, move to base of the PR (the output of `git merge-base HEAD origin/master`)

  git reset --mixed PR_base

Not you have all your changes, uncommitted. You can use `git add --interactive` or a GUI to pick changes you want to place to the first commit. Repeat it until you have all change committed. Then use `git cherry-pick` to split `pr_splitting_branch` into individual branches.